# image from gallery is not displaying on pdf file in android

Tags: android, itext

I am trying to creating pdfs from images in my Android application.
I get the image successfully and created the pdf file successfully. But When I open my pdf file, images are not displayed. I have tried many solutions on Internet but all in vain.
I am pasting my code. Kindly guide me.

First I am pasting the code for getting image from gallery

```
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
             
              startActivityForResult(myIntent,120);
```

Now I am pasting the code of OnActivityResult Method, in which I am getting the image and craeating a pdf file.

```
 try {
    Document doc = new Document();
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 120) {
            if (data.getData() != null) {
               Uri uri   = data.getData();


               Image image = Image.getInstance(uri.toString());
               FileOutputStream fileOutputStream =openFileOutput("mypdf.pdf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                   PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fileOutputStream);
                   doc.open();
                   doc.add(image);

                   doc.close();


            }
        }
    }
    } catch (IOException | DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `Image.getInstance(String)` is expecting a filesystem path, and you do not have a filesystem path.

Comment: I used path also like following.
        Image image = Image.getInstance(uri.getPath());
                   
               But nothing happen. Image is not Displaying on Pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, The solution was to use Input Stream as follows:

```
 Uri uri = data.getData();
        InputStream ims = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        Image image = Image.getInstance(byteArray);
        doc.add(image);
        doc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using iText you need to create BitMap format of image and then need to add into pdf.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, <pass the uri of image>);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , stream);
Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
myImg.setAbsolutePosition(470f,755f);
myImg.scaleToFit(100f,100f);
document.add(myImg);
```